# I need to regex for scriptlet tags?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to find regex pattern in javascript with this value matching

```
1. <script>alert(1);</script>
2. <b>test</b>
```

If the text comes like `<*>*</*>` i should avoid it. Is there any expression to find

I have used these expressions

```
new RegExp("^([a-z0-9]{0,})$");
new RegExp("/<script\b[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)<\/script>/gm");
```

But some how it works but not for all conditions. Can anyone give me correct regex pattern to solve it.

Comment: I don't understand what you want exactly. Can you give more details?

Comment: Is this to try and prevent XSS? Because `<SCRIPT>alert(0)</SCRIPT>` will bypass as you have no case-insensitive flag. Also putting an attribute tag in it (`<script foo=bar>alert(0)</script>`) will pass the check. Not to mention, `<svg/onload=alert(0)></svg>`, `<img/src="1"/onerror=eval(String.fromCharCode(97,108,101,114,116,40,48,41))>`. There's so many ways to bypass this simple check (*If it's to prevent XSS*)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `?` modifier from your Expression:

```
/<script\b[^>]*>([\s\S]*)<\/script>/gm
```

Because the `?` makes your Quantifier ungreedy which means that it will match as few as possible.

more about quantifier [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3206d374(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Ok, but in the text any tag can be given, how can find that using regex?

Answer (score 0):

I your objective is to avoid XSS attack, this way is a weak protection (see https://appvigil.co/documentation/doku.php?id=xss_request_wrapper_is_weak_xss_protection).

This regexp can be used to match script tag.

```
<script>(.*?)</script>
```